# Use same socket.io server for two different node apps.

Tags: node.js, socket.io

New to node with problems with socket.io, trying to connect two different aps to the same socket.io server and have this:

webindex.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080);

io.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.on('color', function() {
    console.log("color server");
    client.emit('calor');
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index_web.ejs');
});
```

mobileindex.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
var db;

server.listen(3000);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://charlie:12345678@ds023674.mlab.com:23674/shapes', function(err,database){
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  db = database;
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  db.collection('shapes').find().toArray(function(err, result){
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    res.render('index.ejs', {shapes: result})
  })});

app.get('/shapes/:id', function(req,res){
  db.collection('shapes').find({"_id": ObjectId(req.params.id)}).toArray(function(err,result){
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result[0]));
  });
});
```

index.js

```js
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

socket.on('color', function(){
  console.log('color');
  sortShapes('color');
});

socket.on('shape', function(){
  console.log('shape');
  sortShapes("name");
});


function sortShapes(by){

  var myArray = $("img");

  console.log(myArray);

  myArray.sort(function (a, b) {

      a = $(a).attr(by);
      b = $(b).attr(by);

      if(a > b) {
          return 1;
      } else if(a < b) {
          return -1;
      } else {
          return 0;
      }
  });

  $("#original").append(myArray);
}

$(function() {

  $("img").mouseover(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/shapes/" + $(this).attr("mongo_id"),
      success: displayShapeInfo,
      error: function(){
        console.log("Error!")
      },
      dataType:"json"
    });
  });

  function displayShapeInfo(shape){
    $('#shape_info').text("type: " + shape.name + " color: " + shape.color + " times seen: " + shape.times_seen);
    addTimesSeen(shape._id);
  }

  function addTimesSeen(id){
    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/shapes/" + id,
    });
  }

});
```

index_web.js

```js
var socket = io.connec('http://localhost:8080');

$(function(){

  $('#color').on('click', function(){
    console.log("color");
    socket.emit('color');
  })

  $('#shape').on('click', function(){
    console.log("shapes");
    socket.emit('shape');
  })
});
```

Why my socket.on in index.js are not working properly?

Im sure the events are triggered correctly.

Comment: Don't use `connect`. `var socket = io();`.

Comment: Also,  if that code is copied verbatim, you've got a typo at `io.connec(`

Comment: Still not working with `var socket = io();`

Comment: Well the browser would have produced an error if `var socket = io();` didn't work. What's the error?

Comment: No error on the browser, not a single clue why this is not working :(

Comment: If it goes past the line `var socket = io();` without an error then it probably connected...

Comment: Then, why `socket.on('color', function(){
  console.log('color');
  sortShapes('color');
});`is not working?

Comment: Are you even serving the socket.io JS file to the client???

Comment: I think so: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes but that is no where in your posted code. If the connection line does not work the browser's console will say something like `io() is not defined`

Comment: I know, but i have no errors on my browser.

Comment: I doubt that is possible. In any case, if there are no errors, and it doesn't work, then I guess there's nothing further I can help with